# map function doesnt reader the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code which doesnt show any list as expected.
I am confused why its not working , whats missing .

```html
return (
    
    <div>
    List
    <ul>
      {events.map((event,index)=>{ 
      
           <li key={index}>Name:{event.name}</li>
         })
       }
       </ul>
    </div>
 
  );
```

Above code is a return block of function component I tried replacing the

with many other tags but it just doesnt return anything expect the text outside the map function.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo - you're using `{` `}` braces there, in which case you'd need a `return` too. Failing to have a `return` in a curly-braced function equals an implicit `return undefined;`.

```
return (
  <div>
    List
    <ul>
      {events.map((event, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>Name:{event.name}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Or, more simply, use regular parentheses to make the return implicit (see [*Concise body* here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)):

```
return (
  <div>
    List
    <ul>
      {events.map((event, index) => (
        <li key={index}>Name:{event.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```